# Paypal recurring payment on event basis not on period basis

Tags: payment-gateway, paypal

I would like to achieve recurring payment through paypal. But according to my research paypal recurring payment is based on time period i.e. weekly, monthly or yearly.

I dont want the payment to be on time period but on an event. Please help me on this.

Comment: Thanks @strkol You have pointed me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is called Reference Transactions:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECReferenceTxns

<del>But you must signup for PayPal Pro.</del>

Comment: Reference Transactions doesn't require PayPal Payments Pro.

Comment: @Robert, thanks, you're correct. I thought that Express Checkout is part of PayPal Pro only (that's how I use it).